# c# - inserting smileys in RichTextBox inserts some and ignores others

Tags: c#, image, winforms, clipboard

I have a code to replace symbols in the richtextbox to smileys, this is the code:

```
private void add_smileys(RichTextBox addin)
        {
            try
            {
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":)"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":)", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_smile;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(">:("))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(">:(", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 3;

                    Image img = Resources.in_angry;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":D"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":D", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_lol;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":'("))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":'(", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 3;

                    Image img = Resources.in_cry;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":("))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":(", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_sad;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(";)"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(";)", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_wink;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains("xD"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find("xD", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_laugh;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":P"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":P", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_tongue;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":|"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":|", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_neutral;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains("^^"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find("^^", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_happy;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains("o.O"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find("o.O", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 3;

                    Image img = Resources.in_dizzy;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":S"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":S", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_confused;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
                while (addin.Text.Contains(":O"))
                {
                    addin.SelectionStart = addin.Find(":O", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
                    addin.SelectionLength = 2;

                    Image img = Resources.in_omg;
                    Clipboard.SetImage(img);
                    addin.Paste();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is the output:
[image]

As you see, some symbols are replaced with smileys and some aren't. moreover, I get this exception:

[image]

What is the cause of this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: you seem to be doing a lot of redundant checking in regards to a while loop why not create a `string[] { }` that contains all of your possible string characters and then implement a single while loop and possible Case Statement if needed.. from first glance it appears that you can do this with a single While loop which is probably not needed but either way you should be able to do the same thing with a switch case statement.. have you stepped thru the code to see which while loop is causing the issue.. ? and why it's happening..?

Comment: @MethodMan appearently the while loop of the "xD" symbol is the one causing the issue I don't know why. and how can I create the string[] while loop? I mean, what do I have to put inside the addin.Text.Contains() method? anyways, thank you for taking time to help me :)

Comment: what I am saying is create a string[] something like this 
`var validChars = new string[] {":)", ">:(", .... };`"
then to check if any of the chars are contained then do the follwoing
`var containsChar = validChars.ToList().Contains(":)");`

Comment: this is very simple to follow the example to create a string[] of characters that you want to check against..

Comment: @MethodMan but I want validChars.ToList().Contains to check for all symbols, not just the ":)"

Comment: it will check for whatever you have in the string array based on what you have set it up as .. also is `xD` if that's a Hex char you may want to see what the string value in regards to converting it to a string is ...but from my example you just create a string array with all the values you are wanting to check... [String Arrays](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0100__String/Initializestringarrays.htm)

Comment: @MethodMan sorry but I don't understand. can you please post an answer with the sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get this exception: enter image description here

[image]

> What is the cause of this error? and how do I fix it?

The `Find` method returns `-1` when the string it is looking for doesn't exist. This value is not valid for `addin.SelectionStart`.

You should first check to ensure the result of the `Find` is greater than `-1` method before attempting to use the value.

```
var selectionStart = addin.Find(":)", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
if (selectionStart > -1)
{
    addin.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
    addin.SelectionLength = 2;
}
```

And your Contains and Find check are redundant. For some reason when you get to "^^" they are returning different results, which is why you are getting the error. But to remove the redundancy, you should use the `Find` method in your loop instead of `Contains`.

```
while (true)
{
    var selectionStart = addin.Find(":)", RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
    if (selectionStart > -1)
    {
        addin.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
        addin.SelectionLength = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I also think that your approach is not very clean. You could use a `Dictionary<string, Image>` to do all of your replacing in a simpler, more maintainable way. You should also use the `@` symbol to escape your strings.

```
private void add_smileys(RichTextBox addin)
{
    var smileys = new Dictionary<string, Image>()
    {
        { @":)", Resources.in_smile },
        { @">:(", Resources.in_angry },
        { @":D", Resources.in_lol },
        { @":'(", Resources.in_cry },
        { @":(", Resources.in_sad },
        { @";)", Resources.in_wink },
        { @"xD", Resources.in_laugh },
        { @":P", Resources.in_tongue },
        { @":|", Resources.in_neutral },
        { @"^^", Resources.in_happy },
        { @"o.O", Resources.in_dizzy },
        { @":S", Resources.in_confused },
        { @":O", Resources.in_omg },
    };

    foreach (var smiley in smileys)
    {
        add_smiley(addin, smiley.Key, smiley.Value);
    }
}

private void add_smiley(RichTextBox addin, string token, Image smiley)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var selectionStart = addin.Find(token, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
        if (selectionStart < 0) break;

        try
        {
            addin.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            addin.SelectionLength = token.Length;

            Clipboard.SetImage(smiley);
            addin.Paste();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @QNightOwl888 very good point and I think that Dictionary example is an excellent alternative as well good example for the OP

Comment: Thank you :) it works now! but when the app interpretes a lot of smileys it become very slow and sometimes crashes, what can I do about this?